# ASP.NET View IEnumerable Item validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-validators

I have this ASP:NET MVC Razor View which has a IEnumerable as model .

I'm creating a table where each line represents a item from the IEnumerable.

I'm using this code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFoo" value="@item.isAdded"
               @(Html.Raw(item.isAdded? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
            @item.FooName
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem=> item.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 70px" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem=> item.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </td>

     </tr>
}
```

My problem is that when I enter an incorrect value for the "Name" property all the other text input get the validation error.

Solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: 'all the input' gets the validation error, do you mean the checkbox field and the text box field get errors? Also why are you putting '@:' on the table elements?

Comment: *All the text box fields get the error as they are supposed but instead of being only that one they all get the error.
My mistake adding @.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

I would remove '@:' from the table elements. Also using the razor syntax I would generate a form tag. That may have something to do with it. Also add the ValidationSummary method.
Is that snippet you posted the complete view?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new class{@class="text-danger"})
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="selectedFoo" value="@item.isAdded"
                   @(Html.Raw(item.isAdded? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                @item.FooName
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem=> item.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 70px" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem=> item.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </td>
         </tr>
    }
}
```

If it's a partial view make sure the property 'Name' doesn't exist on any other fields in the view. 'Name' is very generic, perhaps you should rename it something more descriptive. 'FullName', 'ProductName'. ect....

Comment: Already removed them. No. That snippet is in a partial view that is included in my main view. I'll try add ValidationSummary method.

Comment: If it's a partial view make sure the property 'Name' doesn't exist on any other fields in the view. Name is very generic, perhaps you should rename it something more descriptive. 'FullName', 'ProductName'. ect....

Comment: Can create a chat with me to discuss this?

Comment: Stackoverflow has a chat?

Comment: Yes! You can create for a specific question.

Comment: Sure, though I don't know how to make a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132944/discussion-between-waragi-and-catia-azevedo).

Answer (score 0):

Your `foreach` loop is generating duplicated `name` attributes for each textbox, and the `ValidationMessageFor()` applies to all elements with that name. In addition, you will never be able to bind to you model when you submit your form.

You need to use a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate` to generate your elements (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for more detail)

Assuming your model is `IList<T>`, then

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", style = "width: 70px" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
```

In addition, use the `CheckBoxFor()` method to generate checkboxes (assumes `selectedFoo` is typeof `bool`)

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].selectedFoo)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].selectedFoo, Model[i].FooName)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by creating another instance of the model solely for validation purpose in the view.

```
@{YourNameSpace.Models.Model ValidationModel = new YourNameSpace.Models.Model ();}
```

Than you can use it in the form like this:

```
<div class="form-group">                            
   <input asp-for="@ValidationModel.PropertyName" name="[0].Name" class="form-control" />
   <span asp-validation-for="@ValidationModel.PropertyName" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Or using HTML helper:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => ValidationModel.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```